# Does the idiom 高城深池 have a positive or negative connotation?

Tags: idioms

The dictionary says that this idiom means impenetrable defense (high city walls, deep moat). Does this mean that an individual described with this idiom is stubborn or strong in resolve?

Comment: For "...stubborn or strong in resolve?" try 百折不挠，（bai zhe bu nao)

Comment: Neutral. It's not usually used to describe a person.

Answer (score 2):

It is a neutral term. It describes a property of an object. Not commonly used in a metaphorical sense to describe a human characteristic

高城深池 is typically used to describe a defended city, base and of course, castle.

There are many idioms graphically describe objects with no metaphorical usage.

Example:

一望無際 (cannot see the edge) describe the view of a vast area - *express: vastness*

皮堅肉厚 (tough skin and thick muscle) literally describes a man or an animal with tough skin and thick muscle  - *express: physically durable*

水清山秀 (clear water and beautiful mountains) literally describes a place with clear water and beautiful mountains  - *express: beautiful scenery*

高城深池 literally describes a castle has high wall and deep moat - *express: impenetrable defense*

Answer (score 0):

Slightly positive, good defense is a praise for a castle.